# Weird bug in custom strcmp (C)

Tags: c, pointers, character, c-strings, strcmp

I had a task of writing custom strcmp that will compare two strings kinda ignoring the spaces in them (meaning, `" a b  c"` is `"abc"`) and return some positive number if `str1>str2`, negative if `str2>str1` and 0 if `str1=str2`. Here is the code

```c
int mystrcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    while (*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0') {
        while ((*str1) == ' ') {
            str1++;
        }
        while ((*str2) == ' ') {
            str2++;
        }
        if (*str1 != *str2 || *str1 == 0 || *str2 == 0) {
            return (unsigned char) *str1 - (unsigned char) *str2;
        }
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char) *str1 - (unsigned char) *str2;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work properly with `"ab "` and `"ab"`, which are considered equal. Those whiles should get both `str1` and `str2` pointers to `'\0'`, then subtract them and return 0. Instead, it returns 32, meaning it doesn't get `str1` to `'\0'`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop stops whenever a '\0' is found in one of your string. But the other string might still contains space. When you compare "ab"
and "ab        ", the second string will never be fully iterated other. You need to make sure that both your strings do not end up on a space. Try this fix:

```
while (*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0') {
    while ((*str1) == ' ') {
        str1++;
    }
    while ((*str2) == ' ') {
        str2++;
    }
    if (*str1 != *str2 || *str1 == 0 || *str2 == 0)
         break ;
    str1++;
    str2++;
}
while (*str1 == ' ')
    str1++;
while (*str2 == ' ')
    str2++;
return (unsigned char) *str1 - (unsigned char) *str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop continues while *both* pointers are not at the end; this is not satisfied by exactly one being at the end (meaning it stops as soon as *either* pointer is at the end).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the shared code is that, the outer while loop breaks when any string reaches '\0'. Try below code, it ensures both the strings are looped till end to check the match.

```
int mystrcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    while (1) {
        while ((*str1) == ' ') {
            str1++;
        }
        while ((*str2) == ' ') {
            str2++;
        }
        if (*str1 != *str2 ) {
            return (unsigned char) *str1 - (unsigned char) *str2;
        }
        if ((*str1) != '\0') str1++;
        if ((*str2) != '\0') str2++;

        if ((*str1) == '\0' && (*str2) == '\0')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```